# Pandas remove all 0s until first nonzero value within each level of multiindex

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, multi-index

I'm dealing with a pandas MultiIndex dataset where a lot of the different groups of data (Item 1, Item 2, etc.) have 0s. I only want to delete rows with 0 where 0s are at the beginning of the Item group. If 0s come after a non-zero number, I don't want to delete it. How can I remove all zeroes until the first nonzero value within each group (outside index)?

Original data

```
                          Quantity
Item1           2016-05-08  0.0
                2016-05-15  0.0
                2016-05-22  0.0
                2016-05-29  456
                2016-06-05   22
Item2           2018-03-08  0.0
                2018-03-15  300
                2018-03-21  0.0
                2018-03-29  0.0
                2018-03-05  433
```

Desired output

```
                          Quantity
Item1           2016-05-29  456
                2016-06-05   22
Item2           2018-03-15  300
                2018-03-21  0.0
                2018-03-29  0.0
                2018-03-05  433
```

Comment: And what is your _question_?

Comment: @DYZ see above - I'm trying to turn the first output into the second

Comment: That's not a question. SO is a Q&A site. You ask a question - we help you with an answer.

Comment: @DYZ I state "How can I remove all zeroes until the first nonzero value within each group (outside index)?" and I provide an example. Is it unclear?

Comment: Now you did :) But then you didn't.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Essentially an island-and-gap problem. Every time you hit a non-zero value in the group, you create a new island. Then your job becomes removing those islands 0. The code:

```
islands = (df['Quantity'] != 0).groupby(level=0).cumsum()
df[islands != 0]
```

A slow motion of what happened:

```
                    Quantity   Quantity != 0?   cumsum
Item1   2016-05-08       0.0           False         0
        2016-05-15       0.0           False         0
        2016-05-22       0.0           False         0
        2016-05-29       456            True         1
        2016-06-05        22            True         2
------------------------------------------------------
Item2   2018-03-08       0.0           False         0
        2018-03-15       300            True         1
        2018-03-21       0.0           False         1
        2018-03-29       0.0           False         1
        2018-03-05       433            True         2
```

And in the end, you remove the rows with `cumsum == 0`

Comment: Hi, is it possible to groupby on a specific column without mentioning level? like suppose I want to do groupby(['key']) and perform the action. I replaced level=0 with a specific column but was getting key error. Can you suggest a solution for this?

Comment: @AkhileshPothuri you can do something like this:
`df["bool"] = (df['Quantity'] != 0)`, followed by `df["cumsum"] = df.groupby("group_id")["bool"].cumsum()`, and finally `df.loc[df["cumsum"] != 0]`

Answer (score 1):

Another option: convert the dataframe into a 2D matrix. Replace all zeros with NaNs and do forward fill. That way, all NaNs at the beginning stay NaNs, but those in the middle become something else. Locate the positions of the NaNs and use a mask to remove the corresponding zeros.

```
mask = df.unstack().replace(0, np.nan).ffill(1).notnull()
new_df = df.unstack()[mask].stack()
```